# how to perform a protobuf deserialization in etcd v3 with kubernetes 1.6?

Tags: kubernetes, protocol-buffers, etcd3

In kubernetes 1.6,the information store in etcd v3,I use "etcdctl get" command to get the information as follow:
[image]

my question is how to deserialize the information?how to deserialize the information by "protoc --raw" command?I read the paper on a website:

> "You have the unusual data we caught and fixed in Prevent protobuf
>   storage with etcd2, which is base64 encoded protobuf (etcd2 does not
>   support storing binary values).  In 1.6 we default to etcd3 mode,
>   which supports binary values, and defaults to storing in
>   "application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf" which is the following form for
>   the values
>
> 4 bytes - `k8s\x00` protobuf encoding of runtime.Unknown
>   (pkg/runtime/types.go#Unknown)
>   * the "typeMeta" field set to the same values of kind and apiVersion that would be returned from the API
>   * the "raw" field set to the protobuf encoded bytes for the golang struct identified by typeMeta - no magic number
>
> You can decode this with:
>
> head -4 (strip the magic number) | protoc --raw (decodes the proto)
>
> You can then decode the raw body using protoc as wel."

but I don't know how to perform it,is there any one know that?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl get /registry/namespaces/default -w protobuf | protoc --decode_raw
```

output should be like following

```
1 {
  1: 14841639068965178418
  2: 10276657743932975437
  3: 7839988
  4: 2
}
2 {
  1: "/registry/namespaces/default"
  2: 11
  3: 11
  4: 1
  5: "k8s\000\n\017\n\002v1\022\tNamespace\022c\nI\n\007default\022\000\032\000\"\000*$20b6cdfa-9929-11e7-8b62-005056b549b62\0008\000B\014\010\305\203\351\315\005\020\221\356\217\314\003z\000\022\014\n\nkubernetes\032\010\n\006Active\032\000\"\000"
}
4: 1
```

BTW, I did not find related proto file in the kubernetes source.